# A step in finding the determinant of transpose of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, permutations

The following question involves the permutation group, which I am horrible at handling. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix with entries $(a_{ij})_{i = 1,2 \cdots, n}^{j= 1, 2, \cdots, n}$. The transpose of $A$, $A^t$ is defined to be the matrix $(b_{ij})_{i = 1,2 \cdots, n}^{j= 1, 2, \cdots, n}$ such that $a_{ij} = b_{ji}$.
Let $\sigma \in S_n$ (the permutation group). Prove that:

$$\displaystyle \prod_{i = 1}^{n} a_{i\sigma(i)} = \prod_{i = 1}^{n} b_{i\sigma^{-1}(i)}$$

Using this, conclude that $\det(A) = \det(A^T)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think DonAntonio's answer contains enough information. But I try to make it clear, especially about the last sentence of his answer.

To avoid unnecessary confusion, I show the identity
$$ \prod_{j = 1}^n b_{j \sigma^{-1}(j)} = \prod_{i = 1}^n a_{i \sigma(i)}. $$

By definition of transpose, $b_{j \sigma^{-1}(j)} = a_{\sigma^{-1}(j) j}$. Since $\sigma$ is a permutation, that is, an bijection on the set of indices $\boldsymbol{n} = \{1, 2, \cdots, n\}$, so does $\sigma^{-1}$. Hence if index $j$ runs over $\boldsymbol{n}$, then new index defined by $i := \sigma^{-1}(j)$ also runs over $\boldsymbol{n}$. Therefore
$$ \prod_{j = 1}^n b_{j \sigma^{-1}(j)} = \prod_{j = 1}^n a_{\sigma^{-1}(j) j} = \prod_{i = 1}^n a_{i \sigma(i)} $$
holds because $j = \sigma \sigma^{-1}(j) = \sigma(i)$.

Then we get $\det(A^T) = \det(A)$ using this identity. First, the determinant of $A^T$ is
$$ \det(A^T) = \sum_{\tau \in S_n} \mathrm{sign}(\tau) \prod_{j = 1}^n b_{j \tau(j)}.$$
Since $S_n$ is a group (if you don't know what is a group, all you have to know at here is there is a one to one correspondence between a permutation and its inverse), if permutation $\tau$ runs over $S_n$, so does new permutation defined by $\sigma := \tau^{-1}$. Use the fact that sign of permutation coincides to its inverse, i.e., $\mathrm{sign}(\tau) = \mathrm{sign}(\sigma)$, we get
$$ \begin{align*}
\det(A^T) &= 
\sum_{\tau \in S_n} \mathrm{sign}(\tau) \prod_{j = 1}^n b_{j \tau(j)} \\ &=
\sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \mathrm{sign}(\sigma) \prod_{j = 1}^n b_{j \sigma^{-1}(j)} \\ &=
\sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \mathrm{sign}(\sigma) \prod_{i = 1}^n a_{i \sigma(i)} \\ &=
\det(A)
\end{align*} $$
as required.

Answer (score 3):

But

$$\prod_{i=1}^nb_{i\,\sigma^{-1}(i)}=\prod_{i=1}^na_{\sigma^{-1}(i)\,i}$$

Put $\,\sigma^{-1}(i)=k\iff i=\sigma(k)\,$ and you get

$$\prod_{i=1}^nb_{i\,\sigma^{-1}(i)}=\prod_{i=1}^na_{\sigma^{-1}(i)\,i}=\prod_{k=1}^na_{k\,\sigma(k)}$$

and we're done as the name of the index isn't important...but there's still a small hurdle you must clear out: why when $\,i\,$ runs from one to $\,n\,$ so does $\,k\,$?